# Using static transform publisher within rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rgbdslam (with kinect + freenect driver) to process octomaps which are currently somehow rotated round the x-axis and therefore giving me wrong occupancy grid maps when I try to save with map_saver. I tried to fix this with static_transform_publisher but don't know exactly how to use it. As far as I understood, this has to be added to the beginning of my openni/freenect+rgbdslam.launch - file:

What are the frame_id and child_frame_id?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238144/using-static-transform-publisher-within-rgbdslam/) by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You would use your own frame_id, e.g. "rotated_map", and the frame_id given in the fixed_frame_name parameter of rgbdslam ("map" by default"). If you want the conventional "map" to be the corrected one, just change the fixed_frame_name parameter in your rgbdslam launchfile.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FTUB](https://answers.ros.org/users/26961/ftub/) on 2016-09-01**:
We tried the following but didn't succeed:
< node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="rotated_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 90 /openni_camera  /map 10"/>
and in rgbdslam's launch file
< param name="fixed_frame_name" value="/rotated_map"/>

Thank you very much in advance

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-09-02**:
I'd try `< node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="rotated_map" args="0 0 0 0 0 90 /rotated_map /map 10"/>` and in rgbdslam's launch file `< param name="fixed_frame_name" value="/map"/>`